# My div is larger than the width of my window

Tags: html, css

This is the `css` of my `div`. İ expect the background to fill the whole screen but it is bigger than my screen resolution, so a bottom scroll bar appears

```
.hero-unit {
  padding:60px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: url("../img/bar2.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0;
  height:233px;
  width:100%;
  left:0px;
  background-size: cover;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

Comment: make `.hero-unit{overflow:hidden}` or use `background-size:give px or %` as per you need...

Answer (score 9):

You can use box-sizing

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This makes it so when you add padding, margin, or borders it will not effect the width. (this will not work IE7 and below)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding padding to the already 100% width.

What you need to do (if you are using percentages) is change your padding to be a percentage and make it add up to 100 percent.

For example:

```
padding:5%;
width:90%;
```

---

I also found an alternative using overflow:hidden to remove the scroll bar. This will not remove your issue though as the padding will still overflow the window, just not visibly.

```
html, body
{
    width:100%;
}

body
{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

See the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YRDD5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

remove `padding` if it is necessary then decrease `width`.

Try to keep them in percentages like

```
padding:5%; /*desired value*/
width:80%; /*desired value*/
```

when they will be added, it should be less than or equal to 100%.
If you have `margin` then consider it also. (assume `margin:5%;`)

For Example:

```
<----------------100%---------------->
  margin | padding|   div   |padding | margin
|<--5%-->|<--5%-->|<--80%-->|<--5%-->|<--5%-->|
```

This is same for Horizontal (width) or Vertical (Height) adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the margins and the padding of the body.

Add this block to your body to see if it helps:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Additionally, you're defining padding to an already 100% element, making it larger than the body.

Answer (score 0):

Often horizontal overflow happens due to an element whose opacity is 0. You can't also see the element but it leads to horizontal overflow. Add the following code to css.

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.hidden-thing {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
opacity: 0;
}
```